# How to reduce a data frame by grouping data?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

:)

Is there an easy way to group a particular data set into a reduced data frame from certain characteristics? I was thinking of an algorithm for this, but is there any function in R that can be used for this? I've trying to use `dplyr`, but it didin't work very well...

E.g.:

[image]

P.S .: My data is in an matrix of more than 1Gb, that is, I need a more automatic process.

Example Data:

```
structure(list(Nun = 1:6, Event = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
    Time = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("11:34", 
    "11:36", "8:50", "8:52", "8:54", "8:56"), class = "factor"), 
    User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("U1", 
    "U7"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Nun", "Event", "Time", 
"User"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: What is the time? `H:M`? or `M:S`?

Comment: Is it `U7` or `U2`?  And post the output of `dput(data)`, not a graphics file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarise` from `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)

your_data_frame %>% 
    group_by(User, Event) %>%
    summarise(Duration = max(Time) - min(Time))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `data.table` way.

**Example Data:**

```
x<-structure(list(Nun = 1:6, Event = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), 
    Time = structure(c(1508514600, 1508514720, 1508514840, 1508514960, 
    1508524440, 1508524560), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
    User = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("U1", 
    "U7"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Nun", "Event", "Time", 
"User"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Code:**

```
require(data.table)
setDT(x)

x[,list(Duration = max(Time)-min(Time)),by = list(Event,User)]
   Event User Duration
1:     1   U1   6 mins
2:     2   U7   2 mins
```